# loading .mat and .m files with loadmat in Python

Tags: matlab, python-3.x, loading

I am currently taking a Neural Network course, and I am trying to load a `.mat` file from Python using `scipy.io.loadmat(filename)`, but I keep getting the following error message:

> ValueError: Unknown mat file type, version 101, 58

The same message occured when I tried loading a .m file, rather than `.mat` file, using `scipy.io.loadmat()`.

I don't know how to resolve this issue, so I would really appreciate if someone on here could help me out.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: wow, thank you so much. But then how could I load/run .m file in Python then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>(converting my comments into an answer)</sup>

A `.m` file is a matlab / octave script. You don't "load" a script. Not even in matlab / octave. You can only run it, and this may or may not result in a particular workspace that you can then save into a `.mat` file.

There are "matlab interfaces" for python that you could use to run an `.m` file from within a python session, e.g. the official [MATLAB Engine API for Python](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html), or if you have an older matlab version you could try finding other python matlab interfaces online (a simple google search gave me [pymatlab](http://pymatlab.sourceforge.net/), [mlab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mlab/1.1.2), [mlabwrap](http://mlabwrap.sourceforge.net/) etc). If your .m file is octave-compatible (and you have octave installed) you could also try the [oct2py](http://blink1073.github.io/oct2py/) interface which is known to work well. Once you have one of those interfaces installed, you could either attempt to run the script and then transfer the workspace variables onto python, or save to a .mat file using the interface, and then load it back onto python using `scipy.io.loadmat` as normal.

As for the .mat file giving you an error, the most likely reason for this is that it's a newer version of the .mat specification, which python doesn't recognise yet (what matlab version are you using?). Try loading the .mat file in matlab (or octave) and saving it again with the -v7 option. Python should then open this without problems.

**EDIT:** Here's an example running an octave script via oct2py, saving the resulting octave workspace onto a `.mat` file, and loading the `.mat` file into python.

```matlab
%% file myscript.m located at /home/tasos/Desktop
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```

```python
# from python:
from oct2py import octave as oct
oct.eval("cd /home/tasos/Desktop")
oct.eval("myscript")
oct.eval("save -v7 myworkspace.mat")

from scipy.io import loadmat
D = loadmat("/home/tasos/Desktop/myworkspace.mat")
print D.keys() 
#>>> ['a', 'c', 'b', '__header__', '__globals__', 'ans', '__version__']
print D['a'], D['b'], D['c']
#>>> [[ 1.]] [[ 2.]] [[ 3.]]
```

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed help. I installed octave, and was able to import oct2py function in Jupyter Notebooks with Python. But what kind of Python function do I need to use to run such a `.m` file? And how could I save a `.m` file as a  `.mat` file in Python?

Comment: @user177196 I added an example. hope it helps. I feel compelled to repeat that you don't "load" or "save" a `.m` file. A `.m` file is a script that you run, not a file that 'contains' data.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot load `.m` script-files. These are MATLAB's own script-files and they contain MATLAB code. The function `scipy.io.loadmat` cannot parse this code.

On the other hand, the function can load data from a MATLAB `.mat`-file. This is MATLAB's own data-format within which you store variables and data - but not code.

Reference: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html.

Comment: How could I run a .m script-files? 

Disclosure: I encountered this issue while taking the Coursera course on Neural Networks.

Answer (score 2):

For people coming over this issue again. You can use `numpy.loadtxt()` to read `.mat` files generated by `Octave`.

For example.
In Octave:

```
octave:1> arr1 = [1,2]
octave:2> arr2 = [2,3]
octave:3> save mydata.mat arr1 arr2
```

Then read `mydata.mat` in Python Interpreter:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.loadtxt('mydata.mat')
>>> data
array([[1., 2.],
       [2., 3.]])
```

Comment: This might be the case if your `.mat` file consists of arrays with the same dimensions. However, `.mat` files can be much more complex. You can have mixed data types and arrays of different dimensions, or even nested arrays. Therefore this is not a real solution in my opinion.

Comment: @steTATO Good, can you add an answer for a solution to the problem you identified?

Comment: The accepted answer with `scipy.io.loadmat` worked nice for me after I saved the `.mat` file with the `-v7` option. I tried `np.loadtxt` as well, but as I said, it didn't work for data structures that have multiple different variable types/shapes.

Answer (score 1):

Much easier is to just load your data with:

```
numpy.loadtxt('your dot mat file')
```

Comment: `.mat` file is not a numpy saved text file. So you cannot load it.

Comment: @RahatZaman `numpy.loadtxt()` also works for `.mat`  generated by Octave, atleast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MATLAB Engine API to run .m files and MATLAB functions. it can also load .mat files as well, but could be a bit slow.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html

Answer (score 0):

the scipy.io module can not read the `.mat` file that was saved by the newer h5py format.
You could try using the `h5py` module to load it.
Also, the channel priority is different: column first and row first