# Executing .m with oct2py and Storing in a Variable (without storing .mat on disk)

Tags: python, matlab, octave

From several online ideas (i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45525233/loading-mat-and-m-files-with-loadmat-in-python)), I have this working:

- oct2py (from Octave) runs a .m file;
- I store this on a .mat file;
- And, I import this .mat file with scipy

However, my problem with this approach is that it takes too much time and too much disk space (each .mat has 5Mb. I want to run this thousands of times).

So I would like to:

- oct2py (from Octave) to run the .m file;
- Automatic save to a python variable which scipy will read and make the appropriate conversions.

Is this possible and the right approach?

Code that I have working now:

```
from oct2py import octave as oct

currentdirpath = os.getcwd() # get current directory path
currentfoldername = os.path.basename(currentdirpath) # get current folder name

newfoldername = "autogenerated_mats_" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m_%d_%y%H_%M_%S") #creates the name unique folder that will store all the .mats generated;

os.makedirs(newfoldername) #creates an unique folder that will store all the .mats generated; 
numoftimestoexecute = 2 #How many time would you like to execute

for x in range(numoftimestoexecute):

    dateforname = "autogenerated_m_" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m_%d_%y%H_%M_%S")
    saveworkspace = "save -v7 " + currentdirpath + "\\" + newfoldername + "\\" + dateforname + "_workspace.mat"
    saveworkspace = saveworkspace.replace('\\', '/')

    print("Generating " + str(x+1) + " of " + str(numoftimestoexecute))
    oct.eval("Generate_Data")
    #oct.eval("save -v7 myworkspace.mat")
    oct.eval(saveworkspace)
```

Pseudo-code idea:

```
storegeneration = oct.eval("Generate_Data")
storemyworkspace = oct.eval("save -v7 myworkspace.mat")
```

Then, with Scipy I would

```
from scipy.io import loadmat:
D = loadmat(storemyworkspace )
```

Comment: Why not program everything in Python or everything in Octave? Calling the one from the other can be a nice workaround sometimes, but if you're crossing the boundary thousands of times, it might be worth while to rewrite your code.

Comment: The question is misleading; you are clearly using the Oct2Py python package, not octave per se, even though you're not showing a minimal reproducible example or the part that imports this package. Regardless, if you're _already_ using oct2py, which is what I was going to suggest in my answer, why not just collect variables from your oct2py instance's workspace into python directly?  surely there's no need to save and reload ...

Comment: @CrisLuengo maybe this is the solution. My original idea is that many Electrical Engineering professors use Matlab. I would like to fast extract their complicated Matlab code and use to generate data which will eventually be fed into an ML algorithms.